# Slow Down SymPy's Computations into Smaller Steps

Tags: python, tree, scipy, sympy

I'm playing around with SymPy and it is very powerful. However, I would like to get it to 'slow down' and solve pieces of an equation at a time instead of most of the equation. For instance, given an input string equation (assuming the correct form) like

```
9x-((17-3)(4x)) - 8(34x)
```

I would like to first solve

```
9x-((14)(4x)) - 8(34x)
```

And then

```
9x-(56x) - 8(34x)
```

and then

```
9x-(56x) - 272x
```

And so on.

Another example,

```
from sympy import *
s = (30*(5*(5-10)-10*x))+10
s2 = expand(s, basic=False)
```

Gives me `-300*x - 740` in one step, and I just want a single * done at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the [ideas document](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/gsoc-2014-ideas) produced as a result of the *Google Summer of Code*, this appears to be something yet to be added to the library. As it stands there is no way of doing this for your example, without completely coding something yourself.

The issue of converting algorithms that are not equivalent to human workings, into discrete steps, is discussed and highlighted in the above document. I'm not sure if that'd be an issue in the implementation of expansion, but it's certainly an issue for other algorithms, which machines compute differently for reasons of efficiency.

**tl;dr** This library doesn't support step-by-step breakdowns for your example. Only the *manualintegrate* function currently has step-by-step workings.

Comment: Ok, I figured... However, isn't it possible to break an equation into parts, use sympy on each part, and them combine them back together?

Comment: I don't see why not, but surely then you're labouring over the steps, and defeating the point of using the library?

Comment: My goal is to show the process of solving an equation step by step. The goal isn't to show the answer, but to show the steps a user 'could' take to get the answer

Comment: I'm just not sure of the most efficient way to go about breaking down an equation

Comment: I think you'll have to write something yourself, converting the human steps and printing at each stage. Hope you get something working, or someone comes along with a better answer. If you do, update your question; would love to see it in action. Pick up a maths textbook, or just use Google for the best process.

Comment: I may be wrong, but doesn't this show the order of operations, http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/manipulation.html